# Prevent flashing of div refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

So IE 10 and I believe 11 doesn't flash the refreshing div. Google Chrome on the other hand does.

Is there a way to prevent it from flashing? (looks like loading the page again)

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#responsecontainer").load("watcher.php");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#responsecontainer").load('watcher.php?randval='+ Math.random());
  }, 1000);
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="responsecontainer">
</div>
</body>
```

## UPDATE:

I figured out the issue. I had a css file on the watcher.php page. That seemed to be causing the flickering. I included that file on the main file instead where the ajax calling is happening. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get flashing divs on mine, you must be doing something wrong, Why are you using a timer?

Comment: Hmm.. weird. Are you sure you don't get any flashing on Google Chrome? I've try Chrome on Mac and Windows and both are flashing the div when the timer loads. Do you recommend anything better than a timer?

Comment: I do a simple innerhtml to swap the content.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled your jQuery function since it can't work in a snippet.

1. The `<body>` starts out with `visibility: hidden`
2. The `init(mSec)` function loads on `<body>`
3. `init(1000)` fadesIn the `<body>`
4. You can adjust the time by `init(mSec)` `mSec = (time in milliseconds)`

```js
function init(mSec) {
  delay(mSec);
}

function delay(mSec) {
  setTimeout('initFadeIn()', mSec);
}

function initFadeIn() {
  $("body").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("body").css("display", "none");
  $("body").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="init(1000);">

  <div id="responsecontainer">TEST</div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
    /*$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#responsecontainer").load("watcher.php");
          var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#responsecontainer").load('watcher.php?randval=' + Math.random());
          }, 1000);
        });*/
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Doesn't seem like this is what I'm looking for! Let me show you what I mean by Google Chrome is flicking the div refresh. IE 10 and 11 work fine! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6I4qPN-GRc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Is that flickering on load? Is that an iframe? Use AJAX, it doesn't flicker since there's no refresh involved. Oops you are using AJAX , wow I don't have a clue. :-\

Comment: I figured out the issue. I had a css file on the watcher.php page. That seemed to be causing the flickering. I included that file on the main file instead where the ajax calling is happing. Thanks!